# Session replication with Spring cause NotSerializableException

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat7

I'm trying to configure tomcat 7 clustering with session replication.

I used [this tutorial](http://harald-scheckenbacher.blogspot.com/2013/02/tomcat-7-clustering-and-session.html) and everything works fine on test servlets, which are located in tomcat examples.
 `http://localhost/examples/servlets/servlet/SessionExample`.

So I added some attributes and then stopped one of the nodes, and session was replicated successfully.

But when I move this configuration to my application with hibernate + spring mvc + spring security, And when I've tried to login I always get exception

```
SEVERE: Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid [69845CF0E87B3F0F64FB605FAC1D4987.node1]
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

All my session objects implement *Serializable* interface, in web.xml I've added 
I've tried make *EntityManager* field transient, but it doesn't help. I think that it can be that spring tries to save some bean to session, but I've searched through project and didn't find any session scoped beans.

Does anybody have ideas how to deal with this issue?

UPD:

```
public abstract class AbstractDAOImpl<E, I> implements AbstractDAO<E, I> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7372882616977337461L;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected transient EntityManager entityManager;
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc-driver}" p:url="${jdbc-db-url}" p:username="${jdbc-db-username}"
    p:password="${jdbc-db-passwd}" p:testWhileIdle="true"
    p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="7200000" p:validationQuery="select 1;"
    destroy-method="close" />


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MIQlocal" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource is not *Serializable*.

Make your class field that is an instance of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` `transient` and make sure it is injected by Spring and you're done.

edit: just now I see that you *have* made the EntityManager transient, so I must ask that you provide the relevant code if possible.

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post. Sorry due to company policies I can't share all code. If it not still enough - tell me and I will provide addional code.

Comment: thanks! Well,  now that the obvious cause is out of the way,... Perhaps you somehow save the `entityManager` elsewhere in your code (for example you create a second object and pass and save the `entityManager` in its constructor), or in some other manner you keep a reference to a specific `entityManager` instance?

Comment: Thanks, I've found several places where EntityManager was not transient, and I made it transient. Issue still appear. I will try to find DAOs that are not implementing Serializable.